# swampy.TurtleWorld not working in python 3.4

Tags: python, python-3.4

I m currently learning python using the ThinkPython book, am using python 3.4 and the Anaconda IDE. Part of what I need to continue is to install a module called swampy. I installed it using pip, which worked very well. Importing the module worked too together with tkinter, but I can't use any of the functions in the module. I checked my lib folder, swampy is there and the functions too are in the swampy folder. I can't figure out why its not working. Please I really need help. If the question isn't clear enough please let me know. I have included the code i tried to run and the error message I get each time I try running it

The code i try to run (page 29, Chapter 4 of think Python the version for python 3.4)

```
import tkinter
import swampy
world = swampy.TurtleWorld
bob = Turtle()
print(bob)
wait_for_user()
```

Error Message i got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Mbaka1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 682, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Mbaka1\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
  File "C:/Users/Mbaka1/Documents/Python Scripts/test.py", line 28, in <module>
    world = swampy.TurtleWorld
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'TurtleWorld'
```

Comment: `wait_for_user` tells TurtleWorld to wait for the user to do something, although in this case there’s
not much for the user to do except close the window. 
That is what it says in the book. i checked the swampy folder for `wait_for_user.py` , didn't see any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book shows these directions if you've downloaded the source code:

```
from TurtleWorld import *
world = TurtleWorld()
bob = Turtle()
print(bob)
wait_for_user()
```

If you want to run the code after installing with pip, this should work:

```
from swampy.TurtleWorld import *
world = TurtleWorld()
bob = Turtle()
print(bob)
wait_for_user()
```

The reason what you're doing isn't working is because `TurtleWorld` is a module within the `swampy` package, which contains a functions with the same name, i.e. `TurleWorld`. So when you do `import swampy` and then try calling `swampy.TurtleWorld` you're trying to call a module rather than the function.

Comment: The above code will prolly work, but i can't install tkinter module. I keep getting an error message `could not find a version that can satisfy the requirement Tkinter (from versions)
No matching distribution found for Tkinter`
Thanks very much anyway, indeed TurtleWorld was a module inside the swampy module. Will try and find a way to install Tkinter

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could download the second edition of Think Python here: http://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python-2e/ It uses Python3 and you do not need the swampy package to run the examples given here, as turtle and tkinter (which are used here) come as part of the Python standard library.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently studying that book, too. I solved this problem by adding:

```
import swampy.TurtleWorld
```

to ensure that the TurtleWorld module in the swampy module runs in your shell. This works as long as your Python version is 3.4 or 3.5.