# Swampy:the window of the TurtleWorld closed immediately

Tags: python

I installed swampy properly,but when I tried the next step:

```
from swampy.TurtleWorld import *

world = TurtleWorld()
bob =Turtle()
print bob

fd(bob,100)

lt(bob)

fd(bob,100)

wait_for_user()
```

A window opened but closed immediately.
How can I stop the window from closing so that I can see the turtle and the line?

Here is the result I got:

```
"swampy.TurtleWorld.Turtle object at 0x01B3F2F0"
```

Comment: Probably duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811920/swampy-turtleworld-not-working-in-python-3-4. Swamp is getting overgrown with weeds.

Comment: What version of Python you use? Do you run the script under spyder?